# Contact form 7 not sending every submit

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 on a wordpress site that I made.
The issue that I'm having is that sometimes the contact form doesn't send the input to my email. I've used Flamingo to save every input regardless if the mail is send or not. But even then not every contact form is saved..

This is the site: [link](http://beeverlyfields.com/register/#wpcf7-f16687-p16471-o1)

Is there maybe something wrong with my code? I copied the whole code of contact form 7 to put it in a slide.

This is the code I used in the slide:

```
<div class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f16687-p16471-o1" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
  <form name="" action="/register" method="post" class="wpcf7-form default"  novalidate="novalidate">
 <div style="display: none;">
  <input name="_wpcf7" value="16687" type="hidden">
  <input name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.1" type="hidden">
  <input name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" type="hidden">
  <input name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f16687-p16471-o1" type="hidden">
  <input name="_wpnonce" value="73278d464f" type="hidden">
</div>
<p>Name Captain<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span> </p>
<p>Email Captain<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="email"></span> </p>
<p>Phone number Captain<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap phone"><input name="phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span> </p>
<p>Team name<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap teamname"><input name="teamname" value="Changeable afterwards" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span> </p>
<p>Team players<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap players"><textarea name="players" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </p>
<p><input value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit"><img style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Sending ..." src="http://beeverlyfields.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax-loader"></p>

<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>

</div>
```

I've already changed the "To" and "From" field in contact form 7 like suggested in some other topics.

Comment: Why aren't you using the CF7 shortcodes?

Comment: Because unfortunatly in the slider the shortcodes don't work

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with Contact form message sending. Debug the form code else provide some code hint. so that we can find a solution.